# How can I write on an image using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, image, mousehover

Can anyone help me out how could I load an Image from my computer and write on the picture using VB.net [ 2008 ]. Then text will show only when the mouse is hovered on the location where text is written. I want to write down the location of the picture for say. Please help me with code block, because here you are talking with a noob. thank you

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289768%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You can load an image from your pc using:

```
Dim img as Image = Image.FromFile(your_file_name)
```

Then you can draw text on image using:

```
Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
gr.DrawString("Drawing text", _
              New Font("Tahoma", 14), _
              New SolidBrush(Color.Green), _
              10,10)
gr.Dispose()
```

Comment: This solution will not work for mouse over events unless you swap the images. I would use jQuery/JavaScript to lay the text over the image as a separate element on mouse over.

Comment: @SamStriano: I thought OP was talking about a WinForms app... Anyway, I can't (don't want to) write all the code. This is just a starting point...

Comment: I hear you. +1 for the GDI solution!